# regsitry query - only return value

Tags: batch-file, registry

When I run the below it returns all the entires in the of the registry key. I only want it to retun the value of FileServer102.

Any idea how I can do that?

```
C:\>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Work\Building" /v FileServer

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Work\Building
    FlSrv    REG_SZ    FileServer102
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the FOR/F loop to split your result

```
set "regCmd=reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Work\Building" /v FileServer"

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims= " %%a in (`%regCmd%`) do (
  echo Result=%%c
)
```

Comment: Hi - that will work if "FileServer102" is the same. As I have different servers using different Fileservers then it would still not correspond to the name. Each server uses different fileservers so the name is different on all of them.

Comment: Plus that still returns the whole value: FlSrv    REG_SZ    FileServer102

Comment: To split the value you could use a FOR/F loop, but I don't understand what your problem is with different servers, could you add more exmaples?